# How can I shift the table of contents upwards in Latex?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, koma-script, page, scrartcl

I am writing a paper in Latex using the editor Overleaf. I am using the `scrartcl` class with 12pt font size and for the table of contents I use the packages

```
\usepackage{etoolbox, tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

Unfortunately, my table of contents goes over two pages, with only the very last item on the second page. How can I minimally shift the table of contents up so that everything fits on one page? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. There are several ways to go about this: you could change the geometry of the TOC page using `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` after. Or you could change the spacing of the TOC items. A Minimal Working Example (a code recreating your problem) would help us in giving you a more detailed answer

Comment: I am really bad at latex and I dont know what to send you from my 370 line preamble.
For my table of contents I use \tableofcontents and the earlier mentioned packages... I guess. How do I use newgeometry?

Comment: Off topic: With `scrartcl` you do not need package `tocbibind`. You could use class options `listof=totoc`, `bibliography=totoc` and `index=totoc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your toc looks like exactly, but in general I would suggest playing around with the spacing inside the toc rather than shifting the whole thing.

Since you are using `scrartcl` you don't need the `tocloft` package for adjustments to the TOC. For example, you could change the `beforeskip` value for section entries to fit the table on one page by using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=<length>]{default}{section}`, like so

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5ex]{default}{section}
% In your paper, you can probably afford more space than .5ex if you only need to fit one more line

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Default:

[image]

With `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`:

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of the line spacing. \linespread did unfortunately not work. My documentclass:

\documentclass[twoside, a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}

Could you please tell me how to apply \setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{...} or whatever might work for me? Thanks!

Comment: @EliasGhalib I've edited my answer with a better solution for your situation.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using ``scracrtl`` is crucial information for anyone trying to help you solve your problem. For future questions, consider adding a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and all packages/content that set up the problem, as I have done in my answer.

Comment: I have no idea which of my 1000 packages belong to this problem...

Comment: @EliasGhalib From what I have understood, none of them. The only problem you had was the length of your TOC, determined only by the amount of (sub)sections in your paper...
More importantly, did this answer provide a solution for your issue? If so, let others know by accepting the answer, if not, state any further issues remaining.

Comment: I tried \usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5ex]{default}{section}
but nothing in the TOC changed, even if I variated the value of 5ex

Comment: You don't need ``\usepackage{blindtext}``, I only used it to insert some text in the example...
Are you still using ``tocloft``? Again, I don't think you need it, but if you want to keep it, make sure to put ``\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`` **after** ``\usepackage{tocloft}``.
Without knowing more about your document, that is my last guess though. I am seriously trying to help, but I cannot diagnose something I cannot see.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to delete \usepackage{tocloft} and then use \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.5ex]{default}{section}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120914/discussion-between-elias-thomas-and-schoekling).